# change json formated data by looping... the result is tripled

Tags: javascript, c#, json

i need to change JSON formated data , i want to remove the quotes in the second column y on the dataLevel JSON Array. First in code behind i make function to change datatable to json format with this code

```
public string DataTableToJSONWithStringBuilder(DataTable table) {
  var JSONString = new StringBuilder();
  if (table.Rows.Count > 0) {
    JSONString.Append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++) {
      JSONString.Append("{");
      for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++) {
        if (j < table.Columns.Count - 1) {
          JSONString.Append("\"" + table.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "\":" + "\"" + table.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\",");
        } else if (j == table.Columns.Count - 1) {
          JSONString.Append("\"" + table.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "\":" + "\"" + table.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\"");
        }
      }
      if (i == table.Rows.Count - 1) {
        JSONString.Append("}");
      } else {
        JSONString.Append("},");
      }
    }
    JSONString.Append("]");
  }
  return JSONString.ToString();
}
```

i got the data through jquery ajax and the result is like this:

```
    {"d":"{ "dataLevel":[{"name":"KEBIJAKAN/PERATURAN","y":"1"},
{"name":"LAINNYA","y":"3"},{"name":"UTAMA","y":"3"}],
 "dataStatus" :[{"Level":"KEBIJAKAN/PERATURAN","Status":"BELUM DIMULAI","Level1":"KEBIJAKAN/PERATURAN","y":"1","Proyek":"PJM16.02.UTAMA PKE SOP Penjaminan"},{"Level":"LAINNYA","Status":"BELUM DIMULAI","Level1":"LAINNYA","y":"3","Proyek":"SKL16.02 Menyusun blueprint kegiatan sosial kemasyarakatan (CSR) LPS |SKL16.03.UTAMA Seminar/sosialisasi/FGD dengan lembaga tertentu (termasuk seminar HUT LPS, seminar/sosialisasi/FGD dengan melibatkan anggota FKSSK) |SKL16.04 Peningkatan hubungan kelembagaan, khususnya LPS-BI-OJK"},{"Level":"UTAMA","Status":"BELUM DIMULAI","Level1":"UTAMA","y":"1","Proyek":"SKL16.01.UTAMA Sosialisasi program penjaminan kepada masyarakat"},{"Level":"UTAMA","Status":"ACTIVE","Level1":"UTAMA","y":"2","Proyek":"GAI16.01.UTAMA Menyusun Pedoman Audit Kinerja |PSO16.01.UTAMA Penyusunan kajian organisasi LPS (cary over 2015)"}]}"}
```

then in the aspx page i make this javascript function :

```
function getData(dataPie, tahun) {
  var dataz = jQuery.parseJSON(dataPie.d);
  var DataArray = dataz['dataLevel'];
  //  var data = JSON.stringify(DataArray);
  var countcolumn = countInObject(DataArray);
  console.log(DataArray);
  var JSONString = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < DataArray.length; i++) {

    JSONString += "[";

    for (var j = 0; j < countcolumn; j++) {
      JSONString += "{";
      if (j < countcolumn - 1) {
        JSONString += "name : '" + DataArray[j].name + "' , ";
        JSONString += "y :" + DataArray[j].y + " ";
        JSONString += "}, ";

      } else if (j == countcolumn - 1) {
        JSONString += "name : '" + DataArray[j].name + "', ";
        JSONString += "y : " + DataArray[j].y + "} ";

      }
    }
    if (i == DataArray.length - 1) {
      JSONString += " ";
    } else {
      JSONString += "}, ";
    }
    JSONString += "]";
  };


  return JSONString;
}
```

this is the result i got is tripled...:

```
[{name : 'KEBIJAKAN/PERATURAN' , y :1 }, {name : 'LAINNYA' , y :3 }, {name : 'UTAMA', y : 3} }, ][{name : 'KEBIJAKAN/PERATURAN' , y :1 }, {name : 'LAINNYA' , y :3 }, {name : 'UTAMA', y : 3} }, ][{name : 'KEBIJAKAN/PERATURAN' , y :1 }, {name : 'LAINNYA' , y :3 }, {name : 'UTAMA', y : 3}  ]
```

the result i want is :

```
[{name : 'KEBIJAKAN/PERATURAN' , y :1 }, {name : 'LAINNYA' , y :3 }, {name : 'UTAMA', y : 3}  ]
```

anyone can help me how to fix this?

Comment: none of this is necessary. You shouldn't try parsing json yourself...all main languages can do it for you from objects and arrays and you can use array methods to map to other structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the strings to numbers just loop over the data and change that value from string to number

```
var dataz = jQuery.parseJSON(dataPie.d);
dataz['dataLevel'].forEach(function(item){
    item.y = +item.y || 0;
});
```